# Angular calling shared service data update in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to write some very primitive angular code with 2 controllers and 1 service.

So when I call shared service from controller 1 and update data, I want to use same in my controller 2 `$scope` so that controller 2 `$scope` value can reflect on my DOM.

```
App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log, sharedProperties) {
// Call a new DOM element to so that ModalInstanceCtrl will be called
// Once controller 2 finishes, I want to update a $scope variable here
// $scope.projectList = getProjectList();
});

App.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, sharedProperties) {
// This is a new modal which uses sharedProperties
// Update setProjectList() in service
});

App.service('sharedProperties', function() {
        var projectList = new Array();

        return {
            getProjectList: function() {
                return projectList;
            },
            setProjectList: function(value) {
                projectList.push(value);
            },
        }
    });
```

Once controller 2 calls setProjectList(). I want to auto update $scope value in controller 1 using getProjectList()

Please let me know how I can do that? Also do let me know if any further details needed on same.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But without code it's too broad to explain.

Comment: wait I will add some code

Answer (score 0):

A service in angular is a singleton so if you change data on the service it will be reflected whenever you call that service.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, userData) {
   $scope.favoriteBook = userData.favoriteBook;
    $scope.getFavoriteBook = function(){
    $scope.favoriteBook = userData.favoriteBook;
   }
  });

   app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, userData) {
    $scope.changeBook = function(){
     userData.favoriteBook = 'The Hobbyt';
    }
   });


  app.factory('userData', function(){

   var favoriteBook = 'Harry Potter';

   return{
     favoriteBook : favoriteBook
  }

 })
```

Here you got a service that exposes an object, you can change the value of that object in the second controller and see it reflected in the first controller. Call changeBook(), and then getFavoriteBook()

This is the plunker:
[the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/crpZmOFpSFKTdOJwuVTe?p=preview)

Comment: but I would like to call the getFavoriteBook() in your case in a single context, so ideally it should be like I am in controller 2 and as soon as I update the shared variable, I should call controller 1 method from controller 2?

Comment: Controller 2 in on another scope that controller 1, so you have to let controller1 know that something change to lunch the digest cycle and update the DOM. Usually the modals have callbacks to handle that. Or you can use $broadcast service on the "accept button of your modal" to tell the other controller that something change and call $scope.$apply(); to trigger the digest cycle.

Comment: Ok..I checked again.looks like if I change service variable like a setter in controller 2 and just have a scope variable in controller 1 to access the service getter, it automatically updates it and the view gets updated automatically